# Extra backslash added to the path when appending a file path (string) to a list

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to make a list of excel files in a folder so that I can sort them by date modified and perform operations on the data within each file. When I try to make a list of the files in each folder I'm getting an extra backslash in each file name which I think may be causing an the issue. Will removing the extra backslashes fix the issue? How do I do that? Any help is appreciated.

```
path = r'C:\Users\...'
for dataFolder, expFolder, file in os.walk(path):
    matches = []
    for file_name in file:
        if file_name.endswith('.xlsx'):
            xlsxExt = os.path.join(dataFolder, file_name)
            matches.append(os.path.normpath((xlsxExt)))
            sortedMatches = matches.sort(key=os.path.getctime)
    print("starting", dataFolder)
    print(expFolder)
    print(file)
    print(xlsxExt)
    print(matches)
    print(sortedMatches)
```

Then I get this in return

```
starting C:\Users\...
[]
['a.ppt', 'b.pzf', 'c.xlsx']
C:\Users...\c.xlsx
['C:\\Users...\\.xlsx']
None
```

Comment: Each backslash in a string gets doubled up when you print it as part of a list.  That's a side effect of printing, the string itself still only contains a single backslash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the backslashes - the python string representation of a backslash literal needs to be escaped as `\\`, and this just represents a single backslash character (using raw strings `r"\"` just saves you from having to write the escaping slash, it is equivalent. *Edit*: Try `len("\\abc")` or `len(r"\abc")` - both will return `4`).

If the issue you're facing is that the last line printed `None`, then its because you used the [`.sort()` method of a list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) which directly sorts the original list, and doesn't return anything. So you can either

- Use the [`sorted()` *function* (not list method)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) to return a new sorted list (this is different).

```py
matches = ['C:\\Users\\abc.xlsx']
sortedMatches = sorted(matches, key=os.path.getctime)
print(matches)
print(sortedMatches)
```

- Continue using the original list `matches` after sorting it directly :

```py
matches = ['C:\\Users\\abc.xlsx']
print(matches)
matches.sort(key=os.path.getctime)
print(matches) # Now sorted
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and solution!

Comment: Note that raw strings can't *end* with a backslash, it gives a syntax error.  Your example of `r"\"` is invalid.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oops, yes, that slipped my mind - thanks for pointing it out ! I've edited my answer.